# How can I change the font color?

Tags: html, css

This is my code to display tree structure.I want to display it in **Black color**. But it is taking **White color**. No where I have mention white. In body I have mention black even though it is giving white. How can I change this.

My code is,
 I didn't mention whole code here, I have mention only required code.

```
<div class="pagecontainer">';
echo "<ul id='treeMenu'>";                      
echo "<li class='contentContainerMain'>";
echo "<ul style='display: none'>";
echo "<li class='contentContainer'>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<ul >";
echo "<li class='contentContainer'>";
echo "</li>";   
echo "</ul>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</li>";       
echo "</ul> 
echo "</div>";<!-- END TREE MENU -->";
```

css is,

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
        color: black;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a.mm {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    background:url(MediaMilan-White.png) left top no-repeat;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
}

/* ---- END CSS RESET --- */

body 
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 23px;

}

.pagecontainer
{
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
        color: #00ff00;
}

img.bg {

        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;


        width: 100%;
        height: auto;


        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index:-1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
        img.bg {
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
        }
}

.ie-six {
    display:none;
}


#treeMenu li {

    padding:0 0 10px 10px;

}

#treeMenu li {
    cursor: default;
}

#treeMenu li.contentContainer  {
    background:url('right.png ') no-repeat -3px 6px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

#treeMenu li.contentViewing {
        background:url('down.png ') no-repeat -4px 6px;

        cursor: pointer;
}
#treeMenu li.contentContainerMain  {
    background:url('right.png ') no-repeat -3px 6px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

#treeMenu li.contentViewingMain {
        background:url('down.png ') no-repeat -4px 6px;

        cursor: pointer;
}
.contentContainer ul, .contentViewing ul, .contentContainerMain ul, .contentViewingMain ul {

    margin:15px 0 0 10px;

}
```

Comment: There are syntax issues with your PHP. Please fix and edit.

Comment: Create a simplified (HTML/CSS only) Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) about the problem and on the way you'll probably figure out yourself what is wrong.If you don't, at least you have a Fiddle which makes it easier for people to help you debug it.

Comment: Don't use JS Fiddle. Click the Stack Snippet button in the question editor and put a live demo in the question itself. Show us HTML instead of PHP.

Comment: Given that code … the text isn't white… there just **isn't any text**!

Comment: @Vidya where is your text at? without knowing where the text at, its impossible to provide direct answer, anyway, I've added an answer to generally make color is black.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this css,

```
    .pagecontainer #treeMenu{
    color:#000
    }
```

or you can just check in html `<li><font color="#000">This is some text!</font></li>`

if your text is inside either `<p>` or `<h1>` (h2, h3 etc..) , then you can use targeted css as follows,

```
p{color:#000;}

h1{color:#000;}
```

Although given your question, I've no idea where will your text located at. If you add some text at the correct location, it'll be more helpful

Comment: Not my dv, but I see the styles for `.pagecontainer` is defined already, seems like OP don't have error reporting in php and hence the white screen not text ;)

Comment: @bhansa thanks, but I've included css for not only that, but for #treeMenu